Read .json file in AndroidManifest.xml file in flutter project
Below is the code of AndroidManifest.xml file in which i have a property for appid adds and i want to read this value from json file

appName\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application
    android:label="tokyoguid"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
   
    This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
    android:name="flutterEmbedding"
    android:value="2" />
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    
    **android:value="888888888888888jdjsj888888"/>**
    **<!-- I want to read this value form my json file -->**
</application>


appName\assets\jsons\text.json

read this value in AndroidManifest.xml
{
"someValue": "888888888888888jdjsj888888" }


Add your key to local.properties of android folder like ADDKEY=your_key_here_do_not_wrap_in_quote
In module level build.gradle file add below code
android {

    defaultConfig {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
        manifestPlaceholders = [addkey: "${properties.getProperty('ADDKEY')}"]
    }
}

And then use in manifest file like...
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="${addkey}" />


the key should come form json
